# XML/DTD showing some errors

Tags: xml, dtd

Please, I need some help as I am trying to validate my XML but the DTD is showing 3 errors that I can't find.

XML:

```
<item>
        <image>images/ejournal.jpg</image>
        <title>Internet TESL Journal</title>
        <type>eJournal/eMagazine</type>
        <editform>https://ecu.on.worldcat.org/oclc/44511716#editions-panel44511716-section</editform>
        <author>
            <fname>Internet TESL Journal (Firm)</fname>
            <sname></sname>
            <alink>https://ecu.on.worldcat.org/search?queryString=au:Internet%20TESL%20Journal%20(Firm)&amp;databaseList=638</alink>
        </author>
        <year>1995</year>
        <link>https://ecu.on.worldcat.org/oclc/44511716</link>
        <vlink></vlink>
        <description>
            <summary>Each issue contains articles, research papers, lessons plans, classroom handouts, teaching ideas &amp; links. Also includes articles, lessons and handouts from previous issues from 1995 on. </summary>
            <publication>Toyota, Japan : Internet TESL Journal, 1995.</publication>
            <language>English</language>
            <database>WorldCat </database>
            <oclc>44511716 </oclc>
            <genre>Electronic journals, Periodicals. </genre>
            <issn></issn>
            <isbn></isbn>
        </description>
    </item>
```

and DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT library (item+)>
<!ELEMENT item (image,title,type,editform,author+,year,link,vlink,description)>
<!ATTLIST item CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (fname,sname,alink)>
<!ATTLIST author CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT fname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT alink (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT link (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT vlink (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (summary,publication,language,database,oclc,issn,isbn)>
<!ATTLIST description CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT summary (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publication (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT database (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT oclc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT issn (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
```

Validator giving the following errors:

> Error Code: -1072896764 Error Reason: A name was started with an
>   invalid character. Error Line: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `ATTLIST` declarations. You simply forgot to add the actual `attribute-name`!

The overall form is:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type attribute-value>
```

Which does not match to:

```
<!ATTLIST item   CDATA #REQUIRED>
               ^
               |
         attribute-name missing here
```

**Simple solution:** Remove the ATTLIST from your DTD

By the way: Why not use XSD for validation?

Comment: Thank you very much!!

I`m not using XSD because it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The three ATTLIST entries are incorrect.

My parser reports:

*The attribute type is required in the declaration of attribute "CDATA" for element "item".*

Since none of the elements have any attributes, you don't need an ATTLIST.